# When I run script/console in my rails app, I got error readline.bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with running 'script/console'

Environments

os : macosx

ruby version : ruby 1.8.7p5000 (2009-03-03) [i386-darwin9.6.0]

rails version : Rails 2.3.2

---

Loading development environment (Rails 2.2.2)

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-darwin9.6.0/readline.bundle: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-darwin9.6.0/readline.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rl_filename_completion_function (LoadError)

Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-darwin9.6.0/readline.bundle

Expected in: flat namespace

- /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-darwin9.6.0/readline.bundle

  ```
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/completion.rb:10

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `require'

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `load_modules'

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `each'

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `load_modules'

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:21:in `setup'

  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:54:in `start'

  from /usr/local/bin/irb:13
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be described [here](http://hivelogic.com/articles/view/updates-to-the-rails-os-x-build-instructions).  Specifically, the last comment by Matthew Hutchinson says to do this:

> Download ruby source again, extract
>   it, then go into ext/readline in the
>   ruby source directory and type:

```
ruby extconf.rb 
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks Jim.
I just reinstalled ruby and rails.
no more errors.